# making an excel file out of mysql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, excel

i am making an excel file something like report my code as below

```
import mysql.connector
import xlwt
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

connn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='root',host='localhost',port='3306',database='attendence')

company_name = 'MCC-INDIA'
sort_user = 'MCCuser0036'
from_date = '01-04-2019'
to_date = '27-04-2019'

cur = connn.cursor()

query3 = "SELECT type, username, time_in, address_in, time_out, address_out FROM (SELECT 'attendence' AS 'type', user AS 'username', company_name AS 'cn', STR_TO_DATE(in_time, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'time_in', in_address AS 'address_in', STR_TO_DATE(out_time, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'time_out', out_address AS 'address_out' FROM attendence UNION ALL SELECT 'visit', username, company_name, STR_TO_DATE(visit_time_in, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), location_in, STR_TO_DATE(visit_time_out, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), location_out FROM visits) t WHERE t.username = '"+str(sort_user)+"' AND t.cn = '"+str(company_name)+"' AND time_in BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('"+str(from_date)+"', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('"+str(to_date)+"', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') ORDER BY time_in ASC;"


try:
    cur.execute(query3)
    #data = cur.fetchall()
    book = xlwt.Workbook('record.xlsx')
    sheet = book.add_sheet('sheet 1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    aaa = 1

    sheet.write(0,0,'TYPE')
    sheet.write(0,1,'USERNAME')
    sheet.write(0,2,'TIME IN')
    sheet.write(0,3,'LOCATION IN')
    sheet.write(0,4,'TIME OUT')
    sheet.write(0,5,'LOCATION OUT')


    r = 2

    for r, row in enumerate(cur.fetchall()):
        r+=1
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(r, c, col)

    book.save('record.xlsx')

except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR = ",e)
```

when i run mysql query through different python to see the output then what i see is

```
('attendence', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 29, 8), '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', None, '')
('visit', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 55, 45), '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', None, '')
('attendence', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 15, 17, 56), 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', None, '')
('attendence', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 41, 5), 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 42, 54), 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India')
```

i dont know why i m gettin datetime.datetime in thired column or at index position 2

when i try to see that particular column then

```
2019-04-01 15:29:08
2019-04-01 15:55:45
2019-04-11 15:17:56
2019-04-23 17:41:05
```

can someone pointout what is wrong i m doing
i think something is going wrong while trying to convert mysql query into python but cant find

my excel looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time_in` field is probably typed as a `date`, so the `mysql` library automatically convert it to a python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).

A quick workaround cloud be replacing `sheet.write(r, c, col)` by something like:

```
sheet.write(r, c, col if type(col) is not datetime else col.strftime('desired format here))
```

> See: [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more details about date formatting

Comment: hello @olinox i forgot to mention that time_in field is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Probably `STR_TO_DATE` is returning a `datetime` object instead of a `str`. Try calling [strftime()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) to transform the `datetime` object to a string, then writing that to the desired file.

Comment: hello @Pythia i believe that str_to_date is function of mysql and i have used to convert in_time and out_time column to date for comparison purpose because both column are also varchar